# C# downloading page returns old page

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, system.net

I have problem, i wrote method to get current song on Czech radio. They do not have API so i had to get song from html via html agility.dll
Problem is even though song title changes on page my method downloads old page, usually i have to wait like 20 seconds and have my app closed, then it works.
I thought some cache problem, but i could not fix it.
tried: DownloadString method did not refresh either.

```
public static string[] GetEV2Songs()
{
     List<string> songy = new List<string>();
     string urlAddress = "http://www.evropa2.cz/";
     string data = "";
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);

     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

     if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
     {
         Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
         StreamReader readStream = null;

         if (response.CharacterSet == null)
             readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
         else
             readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));

         data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

         response.Close();
         readStream.Close();
    }

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(data);
    string temp = "";

    foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//h2"))
    {
            if (node.InnerText.Contains("&ndash"))
            {
                temp = node.InnerText.Replace("&ndash;", "-");
                songy.Add(temp);

            }
     }

     return songy.ToArray();
 }
```

Comment: It's possible the issue is in the code that calls this method.  For example, if this method throws an exception or returns an empty array, how is the calling code handling that?  Is there some sort of variable that's held in memory somewhere that may not be updating in the event of a failure in this method?  Also, if you're using ASP.NET, it's worth checking that the page displaying the result isn't caching the result.

Comment: How do you know it's the "old" page?  Songs typically take *more* than 20 seconds and the page includes a carousel with three of them. It may only refresh once every 60 seconds

Comment: Also, the "live" song appears in an `h4` tag, are you looking at the wrong tag perhaps?

Comment: No, the method to get text of current song works, the problem is i even checked source code of the page and live song was changed in h4 element, but my method downloads page with old h4 element with old song.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos! U were right the radio refreshes every 60 seconds, current song, previous, and pre-previous. only if there are ads between songs it switches instantly! thank you really much!
Could you explain though why on browser i can see it changed, but app only after 60 sec? :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like being a caching problem. Try to replace the 4th line with something like that:

```
string urlAddress = "http://www.evropa2.cz/?_=" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```